# Can I use flash (linking to xml file) within a facebook iFrame?

Tags: facebook, flash

Im having a little beginner trouble with an iFrame.

I have a webpage www.1pw.co.uk/bdc which works well,
I thought It would be possible to copy the source code and paste it into my existing I frame.

its basically javascript with an embedded .fla file which links to an xml page, (to grab the images).

The problem is, nothing whatsoever displays in facebook.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>piecemaker</title>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
script here
</script>
<noscript>
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="piecemaker" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="piecemaker.fla" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="scale" value="noscale" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />    
    <embed src="http://www.1pw.co.uk/piecemaker.fla" quality="high" scale="noscale" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" height="100%" name="piecemaker" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer_de" />
    </object>
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make .swf file out of your piecemaker.fla.
If you used Flash IDE (Adobe Flash-something) to create piecemaker.fla, you need to call **Publish** (File -- Publish). After that you'll see file piecemaker.swf in the same folder as piecemaker.fla. Embed that new swf-file into iframe:

```
<embed src="http://www.1pw.co.uk/piecemaker.swf"...
```

You may also need to set width&height in "embed" as pixels (100% won't do).
Good way is to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

And yes, it is perfectly possible to embed flash into facebook-iframe.